# Simple and affordable Windows two factor authentication

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-authentication

has someone a solution for a simple and affordable two factor authentication for RDP similar to the SSH login on a unix machine?

PAT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneFactor might do the trick:

http://www.phonefactor.com/solutions/terminal-services-authentication

Comment: Free too for < 25 users I believe.

Comment: It is. I've used it to provide two factor authentication for web services.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Radius for authentication, all the major two-factor authentication systems are options for you.  You probably need to run the RDP through ISA.

Here's a tutorial I wrote some time ago: http://www.wikidsystems.com/support/wikid-support-center/how-to/how-to-configure-the-microsoft-isa-server-to-support-two-factor-authentication-from-wikid.  Note that IAS has been replaced by NPS in 2008+.

Comment: we don't use radius, because we are looking for a "simple and affordable" solution ;)

Comment: hmm, I find radius to be pretty simple.  And free since the MS radius plugin is free and on linux, freeradius.